# Python selenium scraper works perfect on windows but not on raspian raspbian

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

The purpose of this script is to scrape info from my work schedule. The full script works fine when I run it on my windows laptop but when I try to run on raspian it appears the click.() on the "display_but" variable is not doing its job.The page pulls up fine and logs with no problem, and it even selects an option from a dropdown with no problem. Only when clicking the display button does an error seem to occur. The object is being found as if I print it I get a selenium web object. There are not error messages. When I use drop.click() this appears to work as correct option from dropdown is being selected. I am lost

Below are the workarounds I have tried.
1. Using Keys module to tab to the button and then submitting.
- this results in the correct button being selected but when I "press enter" using keys nothing happens.
2. I tried waiting for element to be clickable using WebDriverWait, expected conditions, and By modules
- this method also works on my windows but not on raspian
3. I have tried adding implicit waits and time.sleep
- these methods did not seem to help

Below is my code

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/Users/Sanch/Desktop/Drivers/chromedriver")

url = 'website'
driver.get(url)

#logs into account
username_xpath = '//*[@id="usernameInputField"]'
password_xpath = '//*[@id="passwordInputField"]'
login_xpath = '//*[@id="submitButton"]/span/input'
user_name = driver.find_element_by_xpath(username_xpath)
user_name.send_keys('username')
password = driver.find_element_by_xpath(password_xpath)
password.send_keys('password')
password.submit()

#selects option from dropdown
drop_xpath ='/html/body/associate/div/view-userschedule/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/select/option[2]'
drop = driver.find_element_by_xpath(drop_xpath)
drop.click()
time.sleep(3)

#clicks display button 
Clicks display button (shows whatever selected in dropdown)
display_but_xpath = '/html/body/associate/div/view-userschedule/div/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/button'
display_but = driver.find_element_by_xpath(display_but_xpath)
display_but.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably do as much of that from the browser context as possible. For example:

```
driver.execute_script("document.querySelector('[id=usernameInputField]').value = 'user'")
driver.execute_script("document.querySelector('[id=passwordInputField]').value = 'password'")
driver.execute_script("document.querySelector('css-for-button').click()")
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by running the script with headless chrome instead of regular chrome. Using the code below in place of "driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/Users/Sanch/Desktop/Drivers/chromedriver")" made it so that the script ran properly.

I am not sure if it was due to the lack of computing power with raspberry pi 3+ or some other factor but everything is working properly now. Maybe someone else can shed light on why headless would work but regular chrome wouldn't. Thanks for the help everyon!

```
#headless driver setup and launch
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")
chrome_driver = "your drivers path"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options, executable_path=chrome_driver)
```